# Linker error because of unresolved symbols from QtRemoteObjects replica definitions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qtremoteobjects

I am working on the project which uses [Qt Remote Objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtremoteobjects-index.html) and I wanted to test one of my components using auto-generated `ReplicaDefSimpleSource` class (see the example below for the details). However, when I tried to link test executable with my library, I got the following linker error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const ReplicaDefSimpleSource::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@ReplicaDefSimpleSource@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

I checked my `MyLib.dll` with DependencyWalker, the required symbol is there:

```
79 (0x004f), 78 (0x0000004e), public: static struct QMetaObject const ReplicaDefSimpleSource::staticMetaObject, 0x00018370, Microsoft
```

I also checked `dumpbin /EXPORTS Debug/MyLib.lib | grep "static struct QMetaObject"`, and again the required symbol is there:

```
?staticMetaObject@ReplicaDefSimpleSource@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const ReplicaDefSimpleSource::staticMetaObject)
```

To build the project I used CMake:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ../
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

To reproduce the problem you need the following files:

- `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test_project)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS
    Core REQUIRED
    RemoteObjects REQUIRED
    Test REQUIRED
)

qt5_generate_repc(GENERATED ReplicaDef.rep SOURCE)
qt5_generate_repc(GENERATED ReplicaDef.rep REPLICA)
set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE SKIP_AUTOMOC TRUE)

add_library(MyLib SHARED a.cpp ${GENERATED})
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

target_link_libraries(MyLib
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::RemoteObjects
)

add_executable(main main.cpp
    # moc_rep_ReplicaDef_source.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(main MyLib Qt5::Test)
```

- `main.cpp`: yep, I know it is not how you are supposed to test Qt code, I just use it as minimal example (e.g. it doesn't have `QApplication`)

```
#include "rep_ReplicaDef_source.h"
#include <QTest>
#include <QSignalSpy>
#include <QUrl>
#include <memory>
void foo();
int main()
{
    foo();  // here no problem with linker
    ReplicaDefSimpleSource source;
    QRemoteObjectHost host;
    host.setHostUrl(QUrl{ "local:main" });
    host.enableRemoting(&source);
    // QSignalSpy is using staticMetaObject that linker complains about
    QSignalSpy spy(&source, &ReplicaDefSimpleSource::settingsChanged);
    spy.wait(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

- `ReplicaDef.rep`:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
class ReplicaDef
{
    PROP(QString settings);
};
```

- `a.cpp`: it actually can be anything, I just put there some dummy function to show that the symbols from `a.cpp` are visible

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
```

As a workaround I can just explicitly include auto-generated sources in my test, but this is not acceptable solution.

```
add_executable(main main.cpp
    moc_rep_ReplicaDef_source.cpp
)
```

The provided example of course compiles and works on any normal system, I just have the problem on windows, which I am forced to use (sorry for asking a question about this platform).

What should I do to test my system using auto-generated replica classes and without compiling their sources multiple times?

As a side question: why the linker does not complain about multiple definitions if I include the replica sources in main executable?

=== EDIT ===

Just to make sure that nothing weird happens when I compile Qt autogenerated code with my hand-written code, I tried to put replica sources in a separate library:

```
qt5_generate_repc(GENERATED ReplicaDef.rep SOURCE)
qt5_generate_repc(GENERATED ReplicaDef.rep REPLICA)
set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE SKIP_AUTOMOC TRUE)

add_library(MyLib-replica SHARED ${GENERATED})
target_link_libraries(MyLib-replica
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::RemoteObjects
)
set_target_properties(MyLib-replica PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
add_library(MyLib SHARED a.cpp)
set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

target_link_libraries(MyLib
    MyLib-replica
)
```

but the problem remains the same. Missing symbols if I do not include autogenerated sources explicitly in each target.